# zVirtualBattery CLSID

Tags: windows, battery

I am trying to install a simulated battery, but I first tried to install the program in Windows 8 and it gave an error while installing WDTF. I changed my computer to Windows 11 and now when I try to open the program, it does not try to install WDTF, but it does not work because there is no WDTF.

[program link](https://www.lab-z.com/zvb/)

error:

```
Bu iletişim kutusu yerine JIT hata ayıklamayı çağırma
hakkında detaylı bilgi için bu iletinin sonuna bakın.

************** Özel Durum Metni **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): {0D972387-817B-46E7-913F-E9993FF401EB} CLSID değerine bileşen için COM sınıfı fabrikasını alma, yandaki hata nedeniyle başarısız oldu: 80040154 Sınıf kaydedilmemiş (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   konum: System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   konum: System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   konum: System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   konum: System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   konum: WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Yüklü Derlemeler **************
mscorlib
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
zVirtualBattery
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 0.7.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 0.7.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/gggg/Downloads/zVirtualBattery/zVirtualBattery.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9206.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Bütünleştirilmiş Kod Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Hata Ayıklama **************
JIT hata ayıklamayı etkinleştirmek için, bu uygulamanın veya
bilgisayarın (machine.config) .config dosyasında
system.windows.forms bölümünde jitDebugging değeri ayarlanmış olmalıdır.
Ayrıca uygulama hata ayıklama etkin durumdayken derlenmiş
olmalıdır.

Örneğin:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

JIT hata ayıklama etkinken, işlenmemiş özel durumlar
bu iletişim kutusunda işlenmek yerine bilgisayarda kayıtlı
JIT hata ayıklayıcısına gönderilir.
```

There is no visual studio on the computer. I looked for the WDTF installation file but could not find it.